# variable probably outside of scope

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

Although the code may seem a little heavy at first (it probably is anyways), it is kinda simple. All I want to do is to read some data from a JSON file (Which is in following format:

```
{"news":[{}]}
```

)
, and push some info into an array that I get from another JSON file that comes from one of newsapi.org's servers. My problem is probably caused by hoisting, but I do not know how to fix it..! In the console it spits out `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`
.

What follows below is a snippet from my defunct code.

(I am aware that my code looks messy :P)

```
function appendNews(id) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=" + id +
        "&apiKey=8fdd732e76664e06b177a20fb295129c", true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest();

    function processRequest() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var container = document.getElementById("newsContainer");
            for (var i = 0; i < response.articles.length; i++) {
                fs.readFile('./data/events/news.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    } else {
                        var file = JSON.parse(data)
                        file.news.push({
                            "title": response.articles[i].title,
                            "description": response.articles[i].description,
                            "url": response.articles[i].url,
                            "urlImg": response.articles[i].urlToImage,
                            "time": response.articles[i].publishedAt,
                            "sourceAndAuthor": response.articles[i].author + " (" +
                                response.articles[i].source.name + ")"
                        })
                        var toStringify = JSON.stringify(file);
                        fs.writeFile('./data/events/news.json', toStringify, 'utf8', function(err) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            } else {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

EDIT: Further down in my code, I use the same variables, and then it works:

```
var holder = document.createElement("button");
holder.setAttribute("id", "newsHolder");
holder.setAttribute("onclick", "openArticle(" + "'" + 
response.articles[i].title + "'" + ")")

var title = document.createElement("div");
title.setAttribute("id", "newsTitle");
title.innerHTML = response.articles[i].title;
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.setAttribute("src",response.articles[i].urlToImage)
image.setAttribute("id", "articleImage");
holder.appendChild(title);
holder.appendChild(image);
container.appendChild(holder);
fadeIn("newsContainer",1,0.01,1);
```

Comment: Can you debug and determine that the response.articles array always returns articles with a title?

Comment: Have you actually checked what's contained in each `response.articles[i]`?

Comment: Oh yes! If not, nothing on my page would load.

Comment: @FrikkOrmestadLarsen if that were the case, you wouldn't be getting that particular error.

Comment: You see, further down in my code, I use the same variable, and it works just fine. It just seems that when it is wrapped in so many layers of if statements, it won't work..

Comment: FYI, `xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest();` does not do what you think it does, though I assume that's why you ended up blindly adding `xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", processRequest, false);` to fix it.

Comment: @patrick but does it really matter..? It isn't really relevant to the case..?

Answer (score 1):

This is a major issue in your control flow:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.articles.length; i++) {
  fs.readFile('./data/events/news.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    ...
    var file = JSON.parse(data)
    ...
    var toStringify = JSON.stringify(file);

    fs.writeFile('./data/events/news.json', toStringify, 'utf8', function(err) {

    });
  });
}
```

Writing like this demonstrates a complete lack of understanding for asynchronous programming, as what really ends up happening is a race condition where the last successful `fs.writeFile()` will append only one entry from `response.articles` to your JSON, even if you were to fix the `TypeError`.

You're expecting the code to operate like this:

```
i=1    2    3    4    5 ... L
   r    r    r    r    r
    p    p    p    p    p
     w    w    w    w    w
```

Where `r, p, w` stands for `fs.readFile()`, `file.news.push()` and `fs.writeFile()` respectively, but what really happens is this:

```
i=1 2 3 4 5 ... L
                 r r r r r ...
                               p   p  p    p  p ...
                                 w   w  w    w  w ...
```

<sup>Your pushes and writes will occur in a non-guaranteed order, they will not necessarily be sequential.</sup>

where `L` is `reseponse.articles.length`, and you're attempting to access `response.articles[i]` when `i === response.articles.length`, so of course there will be no `article` there.

The first change would be to use

```
for (let i = 0; i < response.articles.length; i++) {
```

but that will not fix the race condition explained above, it will just cause `i` to have lexical scope, so at least you won't be accessing out of bounds.

In order to avoid unnecessary reading and writing, you can simply `fs.readFile()` once, loop through your `articles` and push them to `file.news` in the callback, and then `fs.writeFile()` after the end of the `for` loop. That would look something like this:

```
// add your event listener BEFORE sending
xhr.addEventListener('load', processRequest, false);
xhr.send();

function processRequest() {
  // no need to check readyState and status if you use the `load` event
  fs.readFile(..., (err, data) => {
    // handle error
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }

    const { articles = [] } = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    const file = JSON.parse(data);

    for (const article of articles) {
      const {
        title,
        description,
        url,
        urlToImage: urlImg,
        publishedAt: time,
        author,
        source: { name }
      } = article;

      file.news.push({
        title,
        description,
        url,
        urlImg,
        time,
        sourceAndAuthor: `${author} (${name})`
      });
    }

    const json = JSON.stringify(file);

    fs.writeFile(..., (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is what you get for completing a CodeCademy course..? xD
I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @FrikkOrmestadLarsen I'll give you a few pointers. If you make `processRequest()` an `async` function and use [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) on `fs.readFile()` and `fs.writeFile()`, you can `await` their completion inside the `for` loop. But a more optimal way to handle it would be to put your `for` loop _inside_ of `fs.readFile()` and do a single `fs.writeFile()` after appending all the `response.article`'s to your `file.news` JSON.

Comment: @FrikkOrmestadLarsen as for the comment about adding event listener before sending, a well-behaved browser should never have any issues, but occasionally a browser might synchronously invoke the `load` event if the HTTP response to the request is in cache. In theory, this should never happen, but there is a reason that many developers will recommend adding the event listener before sending, just in case.

Comment: Understand. Better safe than sorry ;)